# C++ getline() function bringing in whole file

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

I'm trying to search a document and find a subset to print out that particular line, however, it seems to pull in the whole message at once.

```
ifstream inputFile("searchfile.dat");

  int search;

  cout << "Enter what you're searching: ";
  cin >> search;

  string line;
  //bool notFound;

  while(getline(inputFile, line) /*&& notFound*/){
    if (line.find(search)) {
      cout << line << endl;
      //notFound = false;
    }
    //line = "";
  }


  inputFile.close();
```

This is a homework assignment, so I changed a few of my variables.  Please keep that in mind when answering (ie explain what happened, so I can learn from this)

Thank you so much!

P.S.  Here's the data I'm currently working with:

```
Name1  Name1  1000001  12.00
Name2  Name2  1000002  14.00
Name3  Name3  1000004  16.00
```

I need to search for the 1000000's number and print just the line.  For example, I would search 1000002 and it would print:
Name2  Name2  1000002  14.00

Right now it will print the whole thing

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please. What does the input file look like? Is it one line?

Comment: It's all different lines that look like: first last id wage

Comment: I'm looking for the id

Comment: I'm having a hard time putting the data here.  For testing I have 3 lines.  Name1[tab]Name2[tab]1000001[tab]10.00[endline]Name2[tab]Name2[tab]1000002[tab]12.00[endline]Name3[tab]Name3[tab]1000003[tab]14.00[endline]  Every time I hit the enter tab, it submits the comment, so this is the best I can give you

Comment: Thanks, I did so above and put some more info

Comment: [Here's your MCVE](http://ideone.com/a7StG7).

If you analyse the outputs of this code you'll find that your diagnosis is incorrect; remove the loop and one line is indeed being read, implying that your error is somewhere else...

Please make an effort to produce a **MINIMAL, COMPLETE, VERIFIABLE EXAMPLE** in the future.

Answer (score 3):

For a very basic fix do this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream inputFile("searchfile.dat");

    string search;

    cout << "Enter what you're searching: ";
    cin >> search;

    string line;

    while(getline(inputFile, line) ){        
        if (line.find(search) != string::npos) {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The issues you had were twofold.

Firstly `string::find` doesn't return something which can be correctly evaluated in a boolean context. It returns the index at which the value can be found or otherwise `string::npos`. So if you check for that it will evaluate your if correctly.

The other issue is that you input search as an integer and then try to find it in a string. As a result it is calling this `size_type find (charT c, size_type pos = 0) const;` overload of find, which is trying to find a character. It happens this way because an int can be implicitly converted to a char. You should read in your id as a string or convert it to a string before using it with `find`.

Note a few other things. This code is a bit fragile as it will find that string anywhere on the line, so if a name or wage somehow contained that value it would be found. You also don't need to explicitly close the `ifstream`, it is closed in the destructor.

Comment: @StaceyK you can favourite the answer by accepting it. You can click on the arrow next to the upvote total.